# can you do an ELSE WHEN on a CASE

Tags: sql

```
CASE WHEN P.NURSING_UNIT is not null THEN P.NURSING_UNIT ELSE '' END NURSING_UNIT
    ,CASE WHEN P.UNIT_CODE is not null THEN P.UNIT_CODE ELSE '' END UNIT_CODE, 
    CASE WHEN M.SIGN_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN 'COMPLETED' ELSE 
    WHEN M.SIGN_DATE IS NULL THEN 'UNCOMPLETED' AS ASSESSMENTS
```

error:      because the sp is not compiling now. getting this error message:
        Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GET_SCHEDULE_ALL_DETAIL, Line 18
        Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.
        Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GET_SCHEDULE_ALL_DETAIL, Line 25
        Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

```
    ----

    USE [PRO]
    GO

    /****** Object: StoredProcedure [dbo].[GET_SCHEDULE_ALL_DETAIL] Script Date: 11/02/2011 14:14:50 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO


    alter PROC [dbo].[GET_SCHEDULE_ALL_DETAIL]
    @FACILITYKEY varchar(1000),
    @UNITSTR VARCHAR(100),
    @FromDate datetime,
    @ToDate datetime
    AS
    BEGIN

    (SELECT S.FACILITY_KEY, S.PAT_NUMBER, S.A3A_DATE_USER, M.REFERENCE_DATE ,
    RTRIM(P.LAST_NAME) + CASE WHEN RTRIM(P.FIRST_NAME) <> '' THEN ', '
    ELSE ''
    END + RTRIM(P.FIRST_NAME) PATIENT_NAME
    ,CASE WHEN P.NURSING_UNIT is not null THEN P.NURSING_UNIT ELSE '' END NURSING_UNIT
    ,CASE WHEN P.UNIT_CODE is not null THEN P.UNIT_CODE ELSE '' END UNIT_CODE, 
    CASE WHEN M.SIGN_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN 'COMPLETED' ELSE 
    WHEN M.SIGN_DATE IS NULL THEN 'UNCOMPLETED' AS ASSESSMENTS
    FROM [PC].MDS_M_SCHEDULE S INNER JOIN OPTC.MD3_M_MAST M
    ON S.PAT_NUMBER=M.PAT_NUMBER
    LEFT JOIN OGEN.GEN_M_PATIENT_MAST P ON S.PAT_NUMBER = P.PAT_NUMBER
    WHERE S.PAT_NUMBER=M.PAT_NUMBER AND M.REFERENCE_DATE < GETDATE()
    AND S.A3A_DATE_USER BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
    AND S.FACILITY_KEY IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.ListToTable(@FACILITYKEY,','))
    AND ( @UNITSTR IS NULL
    OR @UNITSTR = ''
    OR CHARINDEX(P.UNIT_CODE, @UNITSTR)% 2 = 1 ))

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT S.FACILITY_KEY, S.PAT_NUMBER, S.A3A_DATE_USER, M.REFERENCE_DATE ,
    RTRIM(P.LAST_NAME) + CASE WHEN RTRIM(P.FIRST_NAME) <> '' THEN ', '
    ELSE ''
    END + RTRIM(P.FIRST_NAME) PATIENT_NAME
    ,CASE WHEN P.NURSING_UNIT is not null THEN P.NURSING_UNIT ELSE '' END NURSING_UNIT
    ,CASE WHEN P.UNIT_CODE is not null THEN P.UNIT_CODE ELSE '' END UNIT_CODE, 'LATE' AS ASSESSMENTS
    FROM [PC].MDS_M_SCHEDULE S INNER JOIN OPTC.MD3_M_MAST M
    ON S.PAT_NUMBER=M.PAT_NUMBER
    LEFT JOIN OGEN.GEN_M_PATIENT_MAST P ON S.PAT_NUMBER = P.PAT_NUMBER
    WHERE M.REFERENCE_DATE < GETDATE() AND S.A3A_DATE_USER BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
    AND ( @UNITSTR IS NULL
    OR @UNITSTR = ''
    OR CHARINDEX(P.UNIT_CODE, @UNITSTR)% 2 = 1 )
    ) --Started

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT S.FACILITY_KEY, S.PAT_NUMBER, S.A3A_DATE_USER, NULL AS REFERENCE_DATE,
    RTRIM(P.LAST_NAME) + CASE WHEN RTRIM(P.FIRST_NAME) <> '' THEN ', '
    ELSE ''
    END + RTRIM(P.FIRST_NAME) PATIENT_NAME
    ,CASE WHEN P.NURSING_UNIT is not null THEN P.NURSING_UNIT ELSE '' END NURSING_UNIT
    ,CASE WHEN P.UNIT_CODE is not null THEN P.UNIT_CODE ELSE '' END UNIT_CODE, 'LATE' AS ASSESSMENTS
    FROM [PC].MDS_M_SCHEDULE S INNER JOIN OPTC.MD3_M_MAST M
    ON S.PAT_NUMBER=M.PAT_NUMBER
    LEFT JOIN OGEN.GEN_M_PATIENT_MAST P ON S.PAT_NUMBER = P.PAT_NUMBER
    WHERE S.PAT_NUMBER NOT IN (SELECT M.PAT_NUMBER FROM [PC].MD3_M_MAST M)
    AND S.A3A_DATE_USER < GETDATE() AND S.A3A_DATE_USER BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
    AND ( @UNITSTR IS NULL
    OR @UNITSTR = ''
    OR CHARINDEX(P.UNIT_CODE, @UNITSTR)% 2 = 1 )) --Not Started
    ) LATE
    WHERE FACILITY_KEY IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.ListToTable(@FACILITYKEY,',')))

    END

    GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard SQL:

```
COALESCE(P.NURSING_UNIT, '') AS NURSING_UNIT, 
COALESCE(P.UNIT_CODE, '') AS UNIT_CODE, 
CASE 
   WHEN M.SIGN_DATE IS NULL THEN 'UNCOMPLETED' 
   ELSE 'COMPLETED' 
END AS ASSESSMENTS
```

If your vendor provides a `REPLACE()` function:

```
COALESCE(P.NURSING_UNIT, '') AS NURSING_UNIT, 
COALESCE(P.UNIT_CODE, '') AS UNIT_CODE, 
COALESCE(REPLACE(M.SIGN_DATE, M.SIGN_DATE, 'COMPLETED'), 'UNCOMPLETED') AS ASSESSMENTS
```

Answer (score 19):

No, ELSE is a catch-all.  In your example, it's not clear why you would want to include a condition in the ELSE clause, since you've already checked the logically opposite condition in the first `WHEN` expression.

However, more generally, you can nest CASE expressions, which would look something like this:

```
CASE
  WHEN m.sign_date IS NOT NULL THEN 'COMPLETED'
  ELSE
    CASE WHEN m.start_date IS NOT NULL THEN 'IN PROGRESS' ELSE 'NOT STARTED' END
END
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you can just remove that else before the when, and add an end before 'as assessments'

```
   coalesce(P.NURSING_UNIT , '') NURSING_UNIT,  -- you can use coalesce here too
   coalesce(P.UNIT_CODE, '') UNIT_CODE, 
   CASE 
       WHEN M.SIGN_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN 'COMPLETED'  
       WHEN M.SIGN_DATE IS NULL THEN 'UNCOMPLETED' END AS ASSESSMENTS
```

Comment: taking out the else - it does not compile

Comment: @Booksman: Don't know why you got a compile error, but this is the best (or at least simplest) answer. Multiple `WHEN` statements act just like an "ELSE WHEN". https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Change this part:

```
CASE WHEN M.SIGN_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN 'COMPLETED' ELSE 
    WHEN M.SIGN_DATE IS NULL THEN 'UNCOMPLETED'
```

to

```
CASE WHEN M.SIGN_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN 'COMPLETED' ELSE 'UNCOMPLETED' END
```

There's no point in having `if (true) { ...} else if (false) { ... }`. Just make the else unconditional.

Comment: this compiles but the app bombs on missing 'assessments'